# How do I configure automatically generated setter stuff in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

#### The question

How do I configure automatically generated setter stuff in Eclipse?

Specifically, how do I configure stuff in the following list?

1. Make the setter parameter `final`.
2. Use the name `newValue` as the parameter name.
3. Don't use `this.` when in the assignment.

#### Explanation

Currently, Eclipse generates setters like this:

```
private String blammo;

public void setBlammo(String blammo)
{
  this.blammo = blammo;
}
```

I would like to configure Eclipse to generate setters like this:

```
private String hooty;

public void setHooty(final String newValue)
{
  hooty = newValue;
}
```

Edit:

#### Why, you say?

This is strictly my opinion.

1. Final parameters = good.  Not final parameters = careless.
2. `newValue` makes sense and fits well with #3 below.  Do you really need to identify the value that the `setHooty` method will be setting?  If yes, then your code has issues.
3. `this.hooty`; why use `this` to reference my own menbers?  I believe it adds no value and thus serves only to obfuscate the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I modify the set method signature that Eclipse auto generates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291625/how-do-i-modify-the-set-method-signature-that-eclipse-auto-generates).  I can't delete the question because there are answers; so I voted to close it.  my bad on the duplication.

Comment: As an aside, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately eclipse will not do that for you but there is a workaround. You can create a template for your setter and getter method and perform actions using `Window->Preferences->Java->Editor-Save Actions`.

You can see existing and create new template using `Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates`.

This question is discussed here in [detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1291625/776084).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that specifically for getters and setters, but you can configure most of this in `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > Additional Actions`