# How to pass parameter into code-template in eclipse-plugin

Tags: eclipse, templates, parameters, eclipse-plugin

I want to create a plugin which defines a new code template ([like this blog post](http://thomaswabner.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/use-your-own-variable-in-eclipse-code-templates/)). How can I pass a parameter into the template? like `${name:param}`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't many things that you can pass into a code template. For example `${word_selection}` contains the current selection.

But what many people are missing is that you can define your own variables:

```
private static final ${type} ${name} = new ${type} (${cursor});
```

Neither `${type}` nor `${name}` are in the list which you get when you click the "Insert variable..." button. Eclipse notices and allows you to cycle through them with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it will keep the content of these custom "template fields" in sync (so you the part after `new` gets filled in if you type in the first field).

[See this answer for other useful Eclipse templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates).

[EDIT] According to the answers in the blog post which you mention, this is only possible at the moment with editor templates, not code templates. I suggest to file a bug against JDT Text to open the API for this.

Comment: i meant from eclipse plugin, when i define my own template.

Comment: Code templates are used by the IDE when it generates code for you (like in "Generate Getters and Setters"). Editor templates is what you get when you type a keyword (that you define) and press Ctrl+Space.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is aimed at Eclipse 4.2 Juno, I have not tested this in any other environment.

All you have to do is pass your parameters, and then you'll have them available.

Say we wanted to create a TemplateVariableResolver that would uppercase the first letter of a passed parameter.

You'll first populate your plugin.xml as follows:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates">
    <resolver class="org.eclipse.ui.templates.UppercaseResolver"
        contextTypeId="java"
        description="${Uppercase(word[, word...])}  uppercase's the provided words"
        name="Uppercase words" type="Uppercase"/>
</extension>
```

You'd also create your custom resolver:

```
public void resolve(TemplateVariable variable, TemplateContext context) {
    if (variable.getVariableType().getParams().size() > 0) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for(String value : (List<String>) variable.getVariableType().getParams()) {
            value = value.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + value.substring(1);
            result.append(value);
        }
        variable.setValue(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Finally in your code Template:

```
String name = ${Uppercase(jim,laughlin)};
```