# Loop over fields in eclipse code template

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, code-templates

Can you do loops in code templates, e.g I want to print all the fields in a class. Is there a template for that?

Comment: I'm also looking for this. I thought https://gist.github.com/pascalalich/436952ccf778e9181ba8 was what I wanted but on Eclipse 4.5.1 it's not printing out the existing fields when I try to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I didn't find what I was looking for, I put it in my [plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/). It supports variations.
If you have `class` called `Company` with fields `companyName`, `companyType`, etc. it will generate print statements as shown below if you select logger.debug variation :

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Company Name " + company.getCompanyName());
    logger.debug("Company Type " + company.getCompanyType());
}
```

[image: template-variation]

Comment: Looks like this plugin is getting more and more useful.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you're talking about `Java > Editor > Templates` a reference (maybe outdated) is [here](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/project_description_file.html)

This SO question [useful-eclipse-java-code-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) containes some examples.

To iterate over class members using a toString() style generator you may find this useful: 
[toString() Generator: Format Templates](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-tostring-templates.htm)

Comment: The link 'useful-eclipse-java-code-templates' just loops back to this question for me.  I think the link was meant to go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse can generate `toString()`, which includes a print out of all fields and their string values, if that's what you are after.