# IntelliJ plugin to print fields from any class

Tags: intellij-idea, intellisense, code-snippets, code-templates

I am new to IntelliJ. Is there a plugin for IntelliJ where I can select a few fields and print them or create jsp form elements, etc. I know they have `toString`, `equals`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no plugin for doing that, and write a "proper plugin" will be hard.

But you can achieve something similar using "Live Templates" (at least for printing fields, Creating a JSP form is a different story)

IntelliJ comes with ready-to-use "Live Templates" like "soutv"...

So you type `soutv` in your java editor, then type `Tab` key and IntelliJ will generate a `System.out.println("myField = " + myField)` and you can choose what file to print.

Check the IntelliJ docs to know how to write your own Live Templates and see some examples.

Comment: Thanks, I have an eclipse plugin that does that as shown here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616493/loop-over-fields-in-eclipse-code-template/3893428#3893428. I will port it to IJ.