# Shortcut key to Snippet in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I use a lot code templates which are great and I do control-space - control-space and choose my templates (down/down etc...)

I would like to have some code templates bind to a key for example the Template 'if' bind to control-meta i

Do you know if that's it possible or is there a plugin for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

CFEclipse plugin might be what you want.
update site: http://cfeclipse.org/update

Comment: CFEclipse is an Editor for Cold Fusion. I don't understand how this can be helpful here

Comment: It includes a "Snip Tree View" feature that supports some kind of shortcut key for its snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Code Templates in Eclipse.
Window->Preferences->Java -> Editor -> Templates

[Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates)

Comment: but it doesn't allow to bind a template to a key