# More coding-templates for Java with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, performance

Are the any useful 3rd party coding templates for Java in Eclipse? Would be nice with some for Collections for example. Any recommended?

By coding templates, I mean:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ${cursor}
}
```

and

```
${array_type}[] ${result:newName(array)} = new ${array_type}[${array}.length + 1];
System.arraycopy(${array}, 0, ${result}, 0, ${array}.length);
${result}[${array}.length]= ${var};
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find any type of code template here. [Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates)