# Useful Visual Studio C# Resharper Code Templates

Tags: c#, resharper, coding-style

As question [Useful Eclipse Java Code Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) suggest some live templates for java, I start to think about some possibilities in C#

ReSharper has Live Templates:
ReSharper -> Live Templates

e.g. (my unique until now)

`tt` is expanded to:

```
[Test]
    public void Test(){}
```

But, out of this scope some other idea. Or about Predefined Templates, exists someone that rocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some I love:

`// $type$: $END$ ($user$ on $time$)`

- Shortcut `com` for comment
- `$type$`: `TODO` is default; first editable
- `$user$`: evaluated to current user name
- `$time$`: evaluated to current date/time

`private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();`

- Shortcut `log` for logger

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert($condition$, "$condition$");`

- Shortcut `as` for assertion
- It is far more productive than the predefined `asrt` template, because it automatically prints out the condition to the assertion dialog

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert($condition$, "$condition$", "$END$");`

- Shortcut `asd` for assertion detail
- If you need some more explanation for the assertion

But, always try to ask yourself, what do you type most. Most valuable live templates will differ from domain to domain.

Apart from that, I really like your `tt` template. I just added it to my templates :) Also I started a new file template that creates the whole default skeleton of a test class.