# synonyms of `sout + Tab` shortcut in IntelliJ IDE for MyEclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea, myeclipse

I using `sout + Tab` shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA for `System.out.println();` statement.
I want know if there are any synonyms of above shortcut in **MyEclipse**?

Comment: I guess this could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates

Comment: *holywar* Do not use Eclipse, use IntelliJ =)

Comment: @DRCB You are right. I found my answer in your suggestion page. If you will write your comment as answer I vote-up it,and accept it as answer. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov This is a solution also ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse you can type the following (so I guess MyEclipse does the same):

```
Sysout + CTRL-SPACE
```

Comment: Or just `syso` + `CTRL` + `SPACE`.

Comment: Yeah, correct. And if you want to have the same as IntelliJ, you can add/edit the Java templates in Eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do something similar in Eclipse (even with slightly less letters to type):

```
syso + CTRL-SPACE  == System.out.println();
syse + CTRL-SPACE  == System.err.println();
```

Those are part of the many predefined templates found in Window > Preferences, Java | Editor | Templates