# How do you avoid repeating yourself when creating a logger?

Tags: java, logging

I think the common idiom for creating instances of `java.util.logging.Logger` is this:

```
public class SomeClassName {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SomeClassName.class.getName());

}
```

My IDE will manage changing the line appropriately when I refactor my code (change the name of the class, for example). It still bugs me that I have to repeat the name of the class, though. What I'd really like to do is something like `Logger.getLogger(getName())` or `Logger.getLogger(class.getName())`, but this isn't legal Java in a static initilization.

Is there a better way of getting at a logger that doesn't involve repeating myself?

Comment: `Logger logger = new logger.getLogger` - I'd be more worried about the impending logpocalypse!

Comment: FYI, see an explanation in the [sl4j FAQ](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#declaration_pattern), different framework but probably same rationale.

Comment: Thanks, @assylias! That FAQ addresses my specific concern very clearly. Namely that "the above logger declaration idiom is not resistant to cut-and-pasting between classes." It does not provide a solution, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Issue 137 of The Java Specialists' Newsletter](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue137.html) deals with this problem. It recommends applying a logger factory, which can detect the actual class name e.g. by generating an exception and analysing the call stack.

I personally find this worse than the original problem, but this is just my 2 cents. At any rate, technically it is interesting, so here it is:

```
public class LoggerFactory {
  public static Logger make() {
    Throwable t = new Throwable();
    StackTraceElement directCaller = t.getStackTrace()[1];
    return Logger.getLogger(directCaller.getClassName());
  }
}

...

public class BetterApplication {
  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.make();

  ...
}
```

Comment: This addresses my specific concern, but I agree that it is worse than the original problem and I won't be using it in my code. Thanks for the ... interesting solution, though! :)

Answer (score 8):

I create an Eclipse code template and use it each time.

[image]

You just have to type `logger` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate it.

Comment: I don't think that's what was asked, as OP specifically mentions that his IDE manages this for him.

Comment: I think the code template tip is valid as the OP mentions his IDE manages changes to the class name, not the original generation of the line.

Comment: PS You can now include imports in the Eclipse code template - makes it even easier.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates

Comment: This doesn't address my specific concern that repeating yourself in this case leaves you vulnerable to copy-paste errors. This is similar to what I currently do. I have a static logger instantiation in my class template. I think your way is nicer, though. I don't have to add an instance until I know I need it.

Answer (score 1):

We do this:

```
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin called log4e which is handy for logging.

http://log4e.jayefem.de/

You can use it to automatically add before/after logging for a method or a whole class.
Also you can get it to auto replace System.out.println's with logger statements.
Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to get the name of current class from a `static` context, I can't cite it from memory but it involved throwing an exception inside the static block and reading stack trace to get to the name of the class. However, it's quite a hack, so in practice I find repeating myself better than playing such tricks.