# Eclipse : Setting up the Ctrl+Space to display "Java Proposals" panel

Tags: java, eclipse

When pressing **Ctrl+Space** on Eclipse, a panel appears, it's usually the "Java Proposals" panel which appears first, and when pressing again **Ctrl+Space** it appears other panel.

I have downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" - Version "2019-12 (4.14.0)" and here, the default **Ctrl+Space** panel is no more the "Java Proposals". I have to press 3-4 times **Ctrl+Space** to find the panel I want.
How can I fix this ? How can I display the "Java Proposals" panel when pressing **Ctrl+space** only one time ?

This configuration disturb me

Comment: [Changing the behavior of the Eclipse auto-complete (Content Assist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590849/changing-the-behavior-of-the-eclipse-auto-complete-content-assist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced` and check your settings. You can change the `content assist cycling settings` and the `default proposal kinds`.