# Why eclipse is suggesting ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

When we are try to instantiate java.util.LinkedList, It is suggesting LinkedList

[image]

Same way, When we are try to instantiate java.util.List, It is suggesting ArrayList

[image]

But, When we are try to instantiate java.util.List, It is suggesting only ArrayList and LinkedList is not an option.

[image]

Actually It is not a problem and manually we are able to do like

```
List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

But What my question is there any specific reason behind this?

Comment: Presumably because `ArrayList` is a far more frequently used implementation of `List` than `LinkedList` is.

Comment: Even Josh Bloch, who wrote LinkedList, [questions how useful it actually is](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248).

Comment: Choose _Preferences_ item of _Window_ menu. In the _Preferences_ window, follow this path: Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced. Then see this _stackoverflow_ question: [Changing the behavior of the Eclipse auto-complete (Content Assist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590849/changing-the-behavior-of-the-eclipse-auto-complete-content-assist)