# Add piece of code to shortcut

Tags: java, eclipse, automation

Is there a way in Eclipse to bound a piece of code to a shortcut?

I use System.out.println() quite often, for testing and other things, and it would be so much easier if I had to press you ctrl + something instead of typing it out every time..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `System.out.println`, you can type something like:

```
"test"
```

Then highlight it, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, type `sysout`, and press enter.

As [Pescis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1690982/pescis) noted [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588255/add-piece-of-code-to-shortcut/15588278?noredirect=1#comment22102111_15588278), you can also type `sysout` followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. It gives you the `System.out.println();` with a focus inside the brackets. (Thanks Pescis!)

To create new templates, go to `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates`.

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) to some ready-made templates, if you are interested.

Comment: I prefer doing it the other way around - typing syso followed by CTRL+space. It gives you the System.out.println(); with a focus inside the brackets. Then there is no need to highlight anything!

Answer (score 0):

Type syso and ctrl + space for System.out.println()