# Change Eclipse Code Template Variable Navigation Order

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-templates

I have an Eclipse code template, say that:

```
${type} ${name} = ${cursor}
```

So, generated code will be:

[image: Sample generated code]

As you see, after code generation variable `type` is selected, but I want `name` to be selected first:

[image: Wanted generated code]

It may seem a stupid question in this case, but for [a template with many variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15705521/471214) which definition of some varibles depend on others it make sense.

So, my question is:

**Is it possible to specify a navigation order on template variables?**