# How to use live templates in eclipse right?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, ide

I know if I write

`sysout` in java code editor and type ctrl+space then `sysout` replaces to `System.out.println();`

and other template:
for example `for`:

```
for (${iteratorType:newType(java.util.Iterator)} ${iterator} = ${collection}.iterator(); ${iterator}.hasNext(); ) {
    ${type:elemType(collection)} ${name:newName(type)} = (${type}) ${iterator}.next();
    ${cursor}
}
```

How to use this template?

What I must to write and what I will see?

[image]

update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *name* of the template is what you have to type before pressing `ctrl`+`space` to use the macro. As you see, there are more than one macro with the name `for` so it will never be inserted automatically but you will have to choose between them. Further, since the name is equal to a keyword, just inserting the keyword will also be offered as an option. It depends on your configuration whether macros are offered immediately in the list of choices or if you have to press `ctrl`+`space` multiple times to toggle between code completion and macro expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can check existing templates and write new templates in:

```
Window->Preferences->Java -> Editor -> Templates
```

Check this question about this: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates).

Comment: my question about. "how to use?"

Comment: what can I type and what I will see after typing?

Comment: you can put any code you want to reuse, to test the new template must go to a java class and write the name associated with the template and press Ctrl + Space