# How to automatically add code to every class I create

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, automation, slf4j

In Eclipse (Java), how do I automatically add code to every class I create. Suppose I create a class called `Foo`, I want this code to automatically go in the preamble/state:

`private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());`

and the appropriate `slf4j` import to be automatically imported. Similarly, I would like the constructor to automatically show up. Full example of what I would like to see after I click the create button:

```
package test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Foo {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public Foo() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Somewhere in option dialog is a way to configure templates.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) and just add `@Slf4j` annotation to your class.

Comment: You could define a Class template as described below, but a far better solution in the long run is to use code snippets produced from keyboard shortcut "slf4j"+ctrl+space, as show here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `New Java Files` and `Class body` templates to get what you want.

In the `Preferences`, under `Java-> Code Style -> Code Templates`, there is `New Java Files` where you would add the imports, at the appropriate place.

[image: Imports]

Change the `Class body` template like this

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

public void ${type_name}() {
}
```

to add the logger and a default, public constructor.

Making those 2 changes will automatically add what you want when you create a new Java class file with Eclipse.

Comment: How do I automatically add an empty constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This should help. You can modify whichever template suits your purpose.

[image: code template]

Comment: That doesn't explain how to do it, just where.

Comment: I was hoping one can extrapolate from the Pattern shown in the screenshot. :-)