# Eclipse - how to create on-class-created template

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I watched the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028858/4336130) about Eclipse -> Java -> Templates and how to create template to decrease code time development but I couldn't find how to:

- generate template on Java class created
- generate the template for some special Java classes which extend `javax.swing.JPanel`

for example how to generate code like :

```
public class AClass extends JPanel {

    public AClass(){this.aMethod();}
    private void aMethod(){}
}
```

...on Java class created?

**EDIT :** 
I try to invoke template code generation on new java source file created (see image)

[image]

I tried to edit the preferences -> Java -> code templates constructor body (see image) but I am not sure how to insert method invoke into constructor body :(

[image]

I tried to input `this.aMethod();` into the edit text area but this doesn't generate constructor body as : `public AClass(){this.aMethod();}`

Answer (score 0):

for question A :

You can edit template through eclipse preferences :

```
Java code style > Code template
```

For question B :

You would have to create a custom new file wizard (a little overkill maybe...)
you can find a simple tutorial on vogella : 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html

Comment: what kind of template should I create in the particularly described example? I mean method which constructor invokes ?

Comment: After being familiar with custom wizard, you should take a look at eclipse internal code. Wizard called when creating a new class is : org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewClassWizardPage 
I said overkill because it's a little complex for the purpose...

Comment: concerning the source code I am not about to modify it right now I just ask is it possible to modify constructor body using template's variables or similar? I tried to edit the "Constructor body" with "java -> code templates" but it seems doesn't do the thing or I am just doing this wrong way?

Comment: You simply add in the popup you posted, the hardcoded method name. Then when using generating constructor (`ctrl+space` in class body or `right clic > source > generate constructor using fields`)

Comment: I tried to enter "this.aMethod();" into the edit template text area but that gives no generation result for constructor body on new java class created :(

Comment: I don't get how to write template for the case I describe; Please give more details