# How to resolve At-clause should have a non-empty description? - Checkstyle - Java

Tags: java, checkstyle, google-style-guide

I am using the google java style in the checkstyle plugin for eclipse luna.  Seeing this error all over my java doc but cannot seem to find how to resolve it.  It's minor but its bugging me.

my javadoc:

```
/**
   * This is a description of something
   * 
   * @throws Exception
   */
```

Error is on the @throws line, Error:

```
At-clause should have a non-empty description
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Typically, you should write

```
 * @throws Exception when this exceptional condition happens
```

e.g.

```
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException when num is negative
```

...and generally explaining *why* that exception would occur.

Answer (score 2):

This is the generic message shown for every parameters in doc starting with '@'.
So for every param you need to add some description.

For example:

```
/**
     * Searches for top cars
     * @param carSearchRequest represents CarSearchRequest body
     * @param userId represents userid
     * @return CarsResponse
     * @throws Exception when userid is null
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this fast so my build doesn't fail from checkstyle, I made an Eclipse [code template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/seeking-useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) to use in the context "Javadoc":

```
${word_selection}
   *           When ${word_selection} occurs.
```

Select the name of the exception, hit Ctrl+Space, choose "throws" (the name I gave the template), and you have a Checkstyle-legal comment:

```
* @throws IOException
*      When IOException occurs.
```

It's a dumb comment, but it's a dumb requirement too.