# Generating Java Bean setters in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javabeans

We use Java beans on some projects where I work, this means a lot of handcrafted boilerplate code like this.

I'm after an Eclipse plugin, or a way of configuring Eclipse code templates that allows a developer to generate the setters from a simple skeleton class, in a similar fashion to the 'Generate Getters and Setters' does for POJOs.

Input

```
public class MyBean {
    private String value;
}
```

Expected output

```
 public class MyBean {
     private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

     private String value;

     public String getValue() {
         return this.value;
     }

     public void setValue(String newValue) {
         String oldValue = this.value;
         this.value = newValue;
         this.pcs.firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, newValue);
     }

     [...]
 }
```

I'm aware of project Lombok, but I'd prefer to stick to a pure Java/Eclipse based approach.

I'm considering writing an Eclipse plugin for this myself, what would be really useful is a more powerful template plugin in Eclipse, that could solve this problem and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple solution that uses the Eclipse code templates. This response is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237108/3795219) which also provides a template for setting up the `PropertyChangeSupport`. I've simply provided additional details regarding the setup process.

In Eclipse, select *Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates > New*. Add the following code template using an unambiguous name, e.g. `BeanProperty`:

```
private ${Type} ${property};

public ${Type} get${Property}() {
    return ${property};
}

public void set${Property}(${Type} ${property}) {
    ${propertyChangeSupport}.firePropertyChange("${property}", this.${property}, this.${property} = ${property});
}
```

Now, simply type `BeanProperty` in your target class, press `Ctrl+Space` to show the Template Proposals, and select the `BeanProperty` template. You can cycle through the field type, field name, and getter/setter names using your `tab` key. Press `Enter` to apply your changes.

See the [Using Code Templates Help entry](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-EditorTemplates.htm) for more details, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028858/useful-eclipse-java-code-templates) for additional, useful code templates. Of course, this solution is still bound by the limitations of the Eclipse, and a more powerful plugin akin to the auto getter/setter tool would be desirable.

Comment: Thanks for this, it definitely makes things easier, I'll probably still end up developing an Eclipse plugin for it though.