# How can I automate logging

Tags: java, javassist

So idea is to write a code which would add some predefined code snippets

e.g.
I want to

1. Generate class field `com.ck.MyClass.DEBUGGER` initialized as `org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog("DEBUGGER." + MyClass.CNAME);`
2. add these below lines at entry point and exit point of all methods except constructors in a  class through java code for all the classes present in my project

   ```
   final String methodName = "process()";

   if (MyClass.DEBUGGER.isDebugEnabled())  {
       MyClass.DEBUGGER.debug(CommonLoggingConstants.METHOD_ENTRY +   MyClass.CNAME + CommonLoggingConstants.HASH + methodName);
   }
   ```

What would be the best approach and API to address this requirement?

Comment: If you are using any IDE like Netbeans then you can create the templates. check the below links. https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-filetemplates.html, https://netbeans.org/competition/win-with-netbeans/customize-java-template.html

Comment: If the code does already exist you can have a look at Aspect Oriented Programming. Otherwise, maybe the IDE can help.

Comment: For templates in an IDE like eclipse, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1029304/3082272

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use Aspect Oriented Programming in java to do anything before and after of any function call in java.

Follow the follwing link to implement it. You can use without Spring also. http://ganeshghag.blogspot.in/2012/10/demystifying-aop-getting-started-with.html
http://kamalmeet.com/tag/aop-2/

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use AOP to intercept all the methods in your application and achieve your goal. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).